# What's the best way to texture a large surface in gazebo?

Tags: ros, gazebo, gazebo-worlds

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey everybody! Long time no write. I hope everyone's projects are going as good as possible.

I again find myself with a dumb question about gazebo. I need to do a world that looks like a soccer field. I know how to do the field, the walls and goals. But I have no idea on how to do the field lines. You know the goal line, the middle-field circle. Is just and aesthetics matter you see, since any rule concerning this lines can be easily done by code. Any way I'll like to make them. Know any example the gives me a hint? I've checked but the worlds I've seen just have walls. Should I make a Blender mesh? or texture? or what is supposed to be that?.

**TLDR:** What's the easiest way to add a "skin" to my soccer field world?

Thanks again for your time and help guys. Have a nice day ;)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10752/what%27s-the-best-way-to-texture-a-large-surface-in-gazebo?/) by [Aidan1488](https://answers.ros.org/users/777/aidan1488/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2011-07-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Aidan1488](https://answers.ros.org/users/777/aidan1488/) on 2011-07-27**:
Thanks for your help :)

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-07-27**:
I'd suggest that a more succinct summary would increase chances of a response.  Paragraphs tend to get skipped over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

An easier way to do it in Blender is using UV/Image texture. [Here](http://www.tutorialsforblender3d.com/Blender3D/BakeTextures/BakeTexture_Blender3D_1.html) you can find a step-by-step tutorial. 
 There are many tutorials about it. Check about UV texture.

---

Originally posted by [Bemfica](https://answers.ros.org/users/540/bemfica/) with karma: 482 on 2011-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Aidan1488](https://answers.ros.org/users/777/aidan1488/) on 2011-07-28**:
Thanks. I'll check it out :)